# gnuplot bar graph not working

Tags: graph, plot, gnuplot

```
plot data_file using 1:2 with box fs solid title ""
```

I am using the above command to plot a bar graph in gnuplot. But the graph generated is a sort of continuous step graph where the width of each box is very high.

What is the problem with the above statement ?? And what is the preferred way to draw bar graph in gnuplot ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow this [link](http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~gzoum01/howtos/gnuplot_barcharts.html)
data.csv is

```
"MCU", 1.8
"Radio Tx", 19.5
"Radio Rx", 21.8
"Flash READ", 4
"Flash WRITE", 20
```

While the content of script should be ( gnuplot.script)

```
set boxwidth 1 relative
set style data histograms
set style fill solid 1.0 border -1
set datafile separator "," 
plot 'data.csv' using 2:xticlabels(1) notitle

set terminal png truecolor font small size 600,500
set output 'image1.png'
replot
```

then

`$ gnuplot gnuplot.script`